# Memory management of static variables in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, static, automatic-ref-counting

I would like to add a static `NSString` to an Objective-C class, however I am wary of managing its memory.

```
NSString *myImportantString = 0;

@implementation MySingletonClass

/* Option 1 */
+ (void)initialize {
    myImportantString = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"criticalFolder"];
}


/* Option 2 */
+ (void)initialize {
    NSString *tmp = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"criticalFolder"];
    myImportantString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:tmp];
}
```

In Option 1, `myImportantString` is an autoreleased object, so how do I know where/when it will be released? This uncertainty prompted me to instead use Option 2. However, as I am using ARC, How/when (if ever?) will it be released? According to the `+initialize` method, `myImportantString` is not used again in the method, and thus wouldn't ARC insert the appropriate `release` code at the end of the `+initialize` method?

I am (relatively) confident that it will be handled correctly for me, but I would still like to know how it works.

Comment: Is `myImportantString` supposed to be local to this .m file or is to be global to the app? If you don't have `extern NSString *myImportantString;` in the .h file, you need to change it in the .m file to be `static NSString *myImportantString;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1 is fine because the global variable `myImportantString` defaults to `strong`. The string will never be released (which is fine for a global).

Comment: And what happens with the previous string when you allocate a new one and set it to the static variable?

Comment: @thibaultd The same thing that happens for any other variable.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was wondering a bit because every comment I've read on the subject highlighted the fact that it never go released.

Comment: @thibaultd A file static variable never goes out of scope so normally it is never released. But if you assign a different value, the old value is released under ARC just like any other value. If you aren't using ARC then you must release the old value, just like with any other variable.

Comment: Yes thanks, I had understood that from your previous answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify the ownership qualifier the LLVM compiler will treat it as __strong. Which means you have not to worry about autoreleasing. Also, considering that a static variable lifespan is as long as the application's lifespan, you don't need to worry about when it gets released either (probably never, but I can't point you to the documentation regarding that). So, both options are fine.